# WPF Web browser control inheriting Internet explorer zoom level

Tags: c#, html, css, wpf, internet-explorer

I have a web browser control hosted on a WPF window so I can display html/css pages. I am having issues with my web browser control using Internet Explorer's zoom factor. The web browser control takes internet explorers zoom level to distort and mess up the way my HTML looks.

For example, if I set Internet Explorer to zoom at 150%, and the web browser will start zoomed in 150%.

I've tried using the zoom CSS property and the HTML document.style.zoom but the browser ignores my changes and takes IE's zoom. Is there a way to ignore Internet Explorer options through either my C# or overwrite them in my HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching through the internet I didn't find too many viable solutions.

I did think of a temporary workaround however. The IE zoomfactor is controlled in the registry key. Setting the registry key there controls what the web browser control sets its zoom to.

```
 var key = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Zoom\\";
Registry.SetValue(key, "ZoomFactor", 0x186a0, RegistryValueKind.DWord); //0x1860a is 100%
```